# How can I use old style task names with the new gulp task api?

Tags: typescript, gulp-4

According to https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task the new way to create tasks is not `gulp.task("xyz" ...)` but instead use `exports.build = build;`
The problem with this approach is, that I can't use old task names like `feature:build`, `feature:watch` anymore, because I can only export valid JS identifiers.

Is there any way to achieve this with the new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by accident.

Each `TaskFunction` has a property `displayName`, which does not just change the name that is used to display the task in the task list or when running, but **also** the task name that you need to pass gulp in order to run it.

So it would be something like:

```
export const myTask :TaskFunction = () => ...;
myTask.displayName = "run:task";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic question. Use the syntax `exports[taskName] = taskFunction;`, for example

```js
exports['feature:build'] = function () {
   // ...
};
```

You may want to read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#Bracket_notation

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, but I noticed I didn't properly ask my question. I'm using gulp with typescript and the default way to export there is just `export foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is: Starting with ECMAScript 2022, it is possible to alias exports with string literals:

```
function featureBuild() { ... }

export {
    featureBuild as 'feature:build'
}
```

See [section 16.2.3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2022/#sec-exports), where the export syntax is defined, you will see that `ModuleExportName` may be a string literal.

The bad news is: I could not find any software that already implements this.

**EDIT:** Node 18.20 and 20.11 understand this syntax. PhpStorm 2023.3.6 still doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for checking back in my question after many years. I haven't tried it yet, but maybe typescript supports or will support it in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found is just to add the function to the `exports` and execute it via Terminal.

In the `gulpfile.js`:

```
exports.your_function = ....
```

and in the Terminal:

```
> gulp your_function
```

Hope it helps.